# apt-get source failing with deb-src uncommented

Tags: apt, deb

So, I've got an uncommented deb-src but am still being told I don't have any source URIs...

```
$ sudo apt-get source sliceconfig
Reading package lists... Done
E: You must put some 'source' URIs in your sources.list
$ cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/makerbot.list 
deb http://downloads.makerbot.com/makerware/ubuntu xenial main
deb-src http://downloads.makerbot.com/makerware/ubuntu xenial main
```

On a lark, I tried moving the line to sources.list, but no joy.

Is it simply that the URI in question points to nowhere, in which case the error message is unhelpfully misleading?

[As requested in the comments, the full output of `sudo apt-get update`]

```
Hit:1 http://prerelease.keybase.io/deb stable InRelease
Ign:2 http://kxstudio.linuxaudio.org/repo gcc5 InRelease
Hit:3 http://nightly.apt.ring.cx/ubuntu_16.04 ring InRelease
Ign:4 http://downloads.makerbot.com/makerware/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Hit:5 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Ign:6 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease
Ign:7 http://kxstudio.linuxaudio.org/repo stable InRelease
Hit:8 http://downloads.makerbot.com/makerware/ubuntu xenial Release
Hit:9 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Get:10 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease [94.5 kB]
Ign:11 http://linux.dropbox.com/ubuntu wily InRelease
Hit:12 http://ppa.launchpad.net/kxstudio-debian/ubuntus/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Hit:13 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates InRelease
Hit:14 http://kxstudio.linuxaudio.org/repo gcc5 Release
Ign:15 http://dl.google.com/linux/talkplugin/deb stable InRelease
Hit:16 http://kxstudio.linuxaudio.org/repo stable Release
Hit:17 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports InRelease
Hit:18 http://ppa.launchpad.net/kxstudio-debian/gcc5/ubuntu wily InRelease
Get:19 http://linux.dropbox.com/ubuntu wily Release [6,596 B]
Hit:20 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable Release
Hit:21 http://ppa.launchpad.net/kxstudio-debian/gcc5/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Hit:22 http://dl.google.com/linux/talkplugin/deb stable Release
Hit:23 http://ppa.launchpad.net/kxstudio-debian/gcc5-deps/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Hit:24 http://ppa.launchpad.net/kxstudio-debian/libs/ubuntu lucid InRelease
Ign:25 http://ppa.launchpad.net/kxstudio-debian/music/ubuntu lucid InRelease
Hit:26 http://ppa.launchpad.net/kxstudio-debian/plugins/ubuntu lucid InRelease
Hit:27 http://ppa.launchpad.net/kxstudio-debian/apps/ubuntu lucid InRelease
Ign:29 http://ppa.launchpad.net/kxstudio-debian/kxstudio/ubuntu lucid InRelease
Hit:30 https://deb.opera.com/opera-stable stable InRelease
Hit:31 http://ppa.launchpad.net/kxstudio-debian/libs/ubuntu trusty InRelease
Hit:32 http://ppa.launchpad.net/kxstudio-debian/music/ubuntu trusty InRelease
Hit:33 http://ppa.launchpad.net/kxstudio-debian/plugins/ubuntu trusty InRelease
Hit:34 http://ppa.launchpad.net/kxstudio-debian/apps/ubuntu trusty InRelease
Hit:35 http://ppa.launchpad.net/kxstudio-debian/kxstudio/ubuntu trusty InRelease
Hit:36 http://ppa.launchpad.net/mumble/release/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Hit:37 http://ppa.launchpad.net/kxstudio-debian/music/ubuntu lucid Release
Hit:39 http://ppa.launchpad.net/kxstudio-debian/kxstudio/ubuntu lucid Release
Hit:41 https://packagecloud.io/slacktechnologies/slack/debian jessie InRelease
Fetched 101 kB in 5s (19.1 kB/s)
Reading package lists...
W: http://downloads.makerbot.com/makerware/ubuntu/dists/xenial/Release.gpg: Signature by key ABB736EB5F9C4CF4A25277973D019B838FB1487F uses weak digest algorithm (SHA1)
W: http://kxstudio.linuxaudio.org/repo/dists/gcc5/Release.gpg: Signature by key 037E0CAFCAA96B99901CB0D52D3445A829213837 uses weak digest algorithm (SHA1)
W: http://kxstudio.linuxaudio.org/repo/dists/stable/Release.gpg: Signature by key 037E0CAFCAA96B99901CB0D52D3445A829213837 uses weak digest algorithm (SHA1)
W: http://ppa.launchpad.net/kxstudio-debian/plugins/ubuntu/dists/lucid/InRelease: Signature by key DF1BC724E4ED8A947FF0B0A1F8599E482BD84BD9 uses weak digest algorithm (SHA1)
W: http://ppa.launchpad.net/kxstudio-debian/music/ubuntu/dists/lucid/Release.gpg: Signature by key DF1BC724E4ED8A947FF0B0A1F8599E482BD84BD9 uses weak digest algorithm (SHA1)
W: http://ppa.launchpad.net/kxstudio-debian/kxstudio/ubuntu/dists/lucid/Release.gpg: Signature by key DF1BC724E4ED8A947FF0B0A1F8599E482BD84BD9 uses weak digest algorithm (SHA1)
```

Comment: Did you run a `sudo apt-get update` since adding the `deb-src` line?

Comment: Yep. That was the first thing I did, before trying the download.

Comment: Post the full output of `sudo apt-get update`.

Answer (score 0):

Update: Ubuntourist (aka kjcole) fixed the issue by correcting the odd Python V3.4 dependency that's inside sliceconfig.

His fix is noted here:  https://github.com/makerbot/mw-scons-tools/issues/27

Instructions on how-to apply his fix are also there... and repeated here:

Download the offending sliceconfig deb install package via:

```
sudo apt-get download sliceconfig --allow-unauthenticated
```

Extract the deb package into its constituent components and then also extract the data.tar.xz
Inside data.tar.xz is the python file: ./usr/bin/sliceconfig
Per kjcole's instructions change the first line from this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3.4
```

to this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
```

Now... recompress the data.tar.xz files
And recompress the original deb package contents (with the updated sliceconfig file) into a tar.xz file
Run this command to convert the tar.xz into a proper .deb install package (nb: you may need to sudo apt-get install alien)

```
sudo alien --to-deb ~/Desktop/filename.tar.gz
```

Now you should be able to use the deb install on your fixed .deb package
Finally... you should then be able to:

```
sudo apt-get install makerware
```